# Visual Studio 2010 closing a tab takes 8 seconds?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Anybody else's VS2010 is extremely slow when closing code editor tabs?

Opening a .cs file is instantaneous but closing a tab takes ~8 seconds. I have uninstalled Power Commands and the Productivity Power Tools, the only other installed extensions are ReSharper (disabling it did not help) and the Color Theme Editor. I do have the [UI Automation Performance Fix](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=27829) installed.

I tried most suggestions from [Visual Studio Optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440/visual-studio-optimizations) question; made sure the settings are saved locally; disabled the outlining mode; disabled the Anti-Virus -- nothing helps.

Googling only finds generic "VS2010 is a pig" complaints back from the Beta1 times. I even tried installing a few recent hot-fixes from https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads (KB2201993, KB2123002, KB2106584, KB981107, B2268081) but nothing seems to help.

Any ideas anybody?

--UPDATE---

Another clue: it only seems to happen for some solutions but not for others! Why would it be solution-specific?!!

Comment: Is it slow when you CTRL-TAB away from it as well?  Or *only* when closing?

Comment: only when closing, switching is fine

Comment: The obvious thing: try uninstalling the rest of the extensions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Deleting **.suo** file helped!

Similar case was reported [here](http://blog.richardszalay.com/2010/01/massive-suo-file-causes-visual-studio.html) but it involved a huge .suo file while mine was <1Mb

Another mention of similar problem can be found [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/e58cd8c6-306d-4668-a4b1-a1bd033547dd) in their case it was the debugger that was impacted.

Thanks to Sysinternals ProcessMonitor for the clue!

Comment: I had the same problem, also just for a specific solution, and deleting the .suo file also helped me! :) Thanks a lot for this solution.

Comment: This didn't fix my problem until I close VS2010 first, then deleted the .suo file. If you delete the file with VS2010 open the problem will persist.

Answer (score 15):

I know you already tried disabling antivirus, but I wanted to post what worked for me. We're inflicted with Symantec Endpoint Protection where I work and I fixed the problem by excluding the solution's folder(s) from auto-protect.  Closing file tabs in VS2010 used to take several seconds, now it's nearly instantaneous.

Here's how:  Under your Symantec's Antivirus and Antispyware Protection -> Options -> Change Settings -> (tab) File System Auto-Protect -> Centralized Exceptions -> Add...[your folder(s)].

Comment: Holy crap, it worked! I'm inflicted with the same lousy program, closing files in VS2010 was taking forever and it was driving me mad, and that was indeed the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Same solution works on VS 2013 with Symantec Endpoint Protection V12. Go to Change Settings -> Exceptions -> Add -> Risk Security Exception -> Folder -> <Project Folder> and in Exception Type: Auto-Protect

Answer (score 6):

After half a year suffering, I just discovered that adding the project's folder to Security Essentials' excluded files & folders list clears this problem for me. Removing the exclusion brings the problem back.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue.  used procmon to find that visual studio was slamming my solution's   .suo file.      I deleted that file and immediately my file closings are immediate.  no more 60 second closing all files!!!    Man, MS needs to fix that problem, It's very bad.